# Tunnelling DELETE through XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() for a REST call

Tags: java, javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest, jscript

I'm unable to perform "delete" from the HTML form. This is my HTML, what's incorrect here? , also included the RESTservice method that performs deletion. I see the POST is getting invoked after every button click.  Any inputs or suggestions  ?

### create_todo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Form to create a new resource</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 

    <script>
     document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();        
        xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/com.dcr.jersey.first/rest/todos", true);             
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "DELETE"); //X-HTTP-Method-Override
        xhr.send();
       },true); 
    </script>

 </head>
<body>

<form id= "myForm" action="../com.dcr.jersey.first/rest/todos" method="post" >
  <label for="id">ID</label>
  <input name="id" />
  <br/>
  <label for="summary">Summary</label>
  <input name="summary" />
  <br/>
  Description:
  <TEXTAREA NAME="description" COLS=40 ROWS=6></TEXTAREA>
  <br/> 
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> <br/> 
  <button id="delete">Delete</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### REST method for DELETE from form

```
 @DELETE
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public void delTodo(@FormParam("id") String id,
          @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
          Todo c = TodoDao.instance.getModel().remove(id);
            if(c==null)
              throw new RuntimeException("Delete: Todo with " + id +  " not found");
            else servletResponse.sendRedirect("../create_todo.html");
      }
```

### RESTResourceClient to post and delete which works fine

```
Form form = new Form();
                form.param("id","45");
                form.param("summary","Summary for id 45");
                response = target.path("rest").path("todos").request().post(Entity.form(form));

                System.out.println("\nPost by FORM response code is "+ response.getStatus()+"\n");

                response = target.path("rest").path("todos/45").request().delete();
```